# How to increase the Label value separately in each row,table contains so many Sections

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a certain number of sections and rows.

When a user selects a cell, how do I perform the actions of plus and minus Buttons in My ViewController? i mean  to increase the Label value for each row separately?

[image]

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSArray *toBeReturned = [NSArray arrayWithArray:
                             [@"A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z"
                              componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];

    return toBeReturned;
}
```

//Cell for Row

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier= @"MyIdentifier";
    LocationsCustomCell *cell= (LocationsCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LocationsCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=locationCustomcell;
    }
    @try
    {
        if(indexPath.section<=[arrayOfCharacters count])
        {
            NSString *sortedStr =[[objectsForCharacters objectForKey:[arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            if([sortedStr isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
            {
                cell.locationNameLabel.text=@"";
            }
            else
            {
                cell.locationNameLabel.text=sortedStr;
                cell.locationNameLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {

    }
    sectionNo=indexPath.section;

     cell.plusButn.tag  = sectionNo*100+indexPath.row;
     cell.minusButn.tag = sectionNo*100+indexPath.row;
     cell.locationCountLabel.tag=sectionNo*100+indexPath.row;

     plusElement=[indexPath row];
   // NSInteger sectionmame=[indexPath section];
   // NSInteger rowname =[indexPath row];
     minusElement=[indexPath row];
     countLabelElement=[indexPath row];

    [cell.plusButn addTarget:self action:@selector(plusButnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    //[cell.plusButn addTarget: self
                      // action: @selector(buttonPressed:withEvent:)
             //forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   // [cell.minusButn addTarget:self action:@selector(minusButnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
}


-(IBAction)plusButnPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"selectedSection Number/plusButn is--%d",sectionNumber);
    LocationsCustomCell *cell=(LocationsCustomCell *)[self.locationsTableVw cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:plusElement inSection:sectionNumber]];
    cell.plusButn=(UIButton *)sender;
    if (cell.plusButn)
    {
        Countvalue++;
        NSString *ValueStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",Countvalue];
        cell.locationCountLabel.text=ValueStr;
    }
}

-(IBAction)minusButnPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"selectedSection Number/minusButn is--%d",sectionNumber);
    LocationsCustomCell *cell=(LocationsCustomCell *)[self.locationsTableVw cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:minusElement inSection:sectionNumber]];
    cell.minusButn=(UIButton *)sender;
    if (cell.minusButn)
    {
        Countvalue--;
        NSString *ValueStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",Countvalue];
        cell.locationCountLabel.text=ValueStr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented Delegate.

Comment: u mean tableview delegate? i implement that one

Comment: Is this your Custom cell if so then you need to implement delegate in your Custom Cell class.

Comment: seems like you have used custom cell. In your rowforindexpath method, set cell.delegate =self and cell.plusButn.tag=indexpath.row and cell.minusButn.tag =indexpath.row. then add target for these button [cell.plusButn   addTarget:self action:@selector(plusButnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; and same for minus button

Comment: It's incorrect to have an index with all letters from A to Z.  The index should only contain those letters for which you actually have rows.  So from your image: H I K L (and no J).

Comment: Your plus and minus buttons are identical to iOS buttons that have a completely different meaning.  For example your minus is used as `UITableView` row delete button.  This is confusing.  iOS has the `UIStepper`, why not use that?

Comment: where is your locationCountLabel in CellforRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 1):

try it

in CellForrowAtIndexPath

```
    [theCell.button addTarget: self
               action: @selector(buttonPressed:withEvent:)
     forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then your event handler would look like this:

```
      - (void) buttonPressed: (id) sender withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
      {
          UITouch * touch = [[event touches] anyObject];
          CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: self.tableView];
          NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: location];

           /* indexPath contains the index of the row containing the button */
         Nsstring *str=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].locationCountLabel.text;

           int a=[str intValue];
            a=a+1;
           [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].locationCountLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",a];

      }
```

and you can done it with minus, same way just decrease value of a.

**Edit**

put this line

```
         [cell.plusButn addTarget:self action:@selector(plusButnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

in     if (cell==nil)  Like this and run your code not my code.

```
    if(cell==nil)
    {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LocationsCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell=locationCustomcell;
            [cell.plusButn addTarget:self action:@selector(plusButnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; /////////this line is put here 

    }
```

Comment: it is showing an error in this line "Nsstring *str=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].locationCountLabel.text;"

Comment: Property 'locationCountLabel' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell *'

Comment: and also change the event UIControlEventTouchUpInside see my edited code.